# Breaking force and translational force

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram, newtonian-mechanics

Let’s say I have a horizontal rod whose total length = ΔXtotal = 5 inches. However, the rod is made up of two pieces (ΔXshaft = 4 inches and ΔXbase = 1 inch) that are welded together, where ΔXtotal = ΔXshaft + ΔXbase and where ΔXshaft > ΔXbase. This rod is horizontally suspended in air by locking mechanisms placed at each end of the total length of the rod.

I want to use a force gauge to bend the shaft at a certain point so that the weld that joins ΔXshaft and ΔXbase breaks. For example, let’s say the weld breaks when I apply 25 pounds to a point on the shaft 1 inch away from the weld (so 5-1=4 inches from the secured end of the shaft).

How much force was applied to the weld and how much force was translated in bending the shaft? I would like to see the applicable equations so I can replicate this process with variable data.